# My makefile cannot compile and said nothing to be done

Tags: c++, makefile

My Makefile is like this:

```
execute: Main.o Student.o Course.o Enrollment.o PrintData.o StoreData.o LoadData.o
   g++ -o execute Main.o Student.o Course.o Enrollment.o PrintData.o StoreData.o LoadData.o
Main.o: Main.cpp Student.h Course.h Enrollment.h PrintData.h StoreData.h LoadData.h
   g++ -c Main.cpp
Student.o: Student.cpp Student.h
   g++ -c Student.cpp
Course.o: Course.cpp Course.h
   g++ -c Course.cpp
Enrollment.o: Enrollment.cpp Student.h Course.h Enrollment.h
   g++ -c Enrollment.cpp
PrintData.o: PrintData.cpp Student.h Course.h Enrollment.h PrintData.h
   g++ -c PrintData.cpp
StoreData.o: StoreData.cpp Student.h Course.h Enrollment.h StoreData.h
   g++ -c StoreData.cpp
LoadData.o: LoadData.cpp Student.h Course.h Enrollment.h LoadData.h
   g++ -c LoadData.cpp
clean:
   rm *.o execute
run:
   make execute && ./execute
```

My main:

```
#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"
#include "Enrollment.h"
#include "PrintData.h"
#include "StoreData.h"
#include "LoadData.h"
```

Student.cpp : 
`#include "Student.h"`

Course.cpp: 
`#include "Course.cpp"`

Enrollment.cpp:

```
#include "Enrollment.h"
#include "Course.h"
#include "Student.h"
```

PrintData.cpp:

```
#include "Enrollment.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"
#include "PrintData.h"
```

StoreData.cpp:

```
#include "Enrollment.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"
#include "StoreData.h"
```

LoadData.cpp

```
#include "Enrollment.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"
#include "LoadData.cpp"
```

I cant run my make file to compile? It keeps giving me "Nothing to be done", or "No targets specificed and no makefile found. Stop". Please help

Comment: when you try to compile, what do you do (and where)?

Comment: did you make sure there are tabs starting line of your compilation rules?

Comment: I used putty to compile, and I use: "make", then it gives me: "No targets specified and no makefile found.Stop". If I use "make make.txt" (my makefile filename), then it gives me: "Nothing to be done for `make.txt'. I did add tab in my compilation rules, I'm afraid it may have something wrong with my syntax for my makefile?

Comment: If your makefile is named `make.txt` then you probably need `make -f make.txt`.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much for your help, it works right now.  May I ask what does -f mean?

Comment: `f` = file, normally your makefile would be called `makefile`, then you wouldn't need `-f`

Answer (score 0):

Rename your makefile or use `-f` option as mentioned in the manual:

> ```
> -f file, --file=file, --makefile=FILE
>     Use file as a makefile.
> ```
>
> make executes commands in the makefile to update one or more target
>   names, where name is typically a program.  If no -f option is present,
>   make will look for the makefiles GNUmakefile, makefile, and Makefile,
>   in that order.